# User flairs overlapping on an edited post

Tags: discussion, user-interface, flair

A [User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180722/mohammad-areeb-siddiqui) with a name of Mohammad Areeb Siddiqui edited a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673234/checking-checkbox-didnt-work-for-second-time). Due to his long username, it's overlapped by the OP's flair.

> [image: overlapped]

The padding should be increased in flairs accordingly.

Comment: Nah, let's just shorten the name.

Comment: yes!!! we can truncate the name.

Comment: Don't think it's a real issue. It's the same behavior in other places too like [badges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/296/html).

Comment: I'm all for limiting usernames! Let us limit usernames to 1.45 inches, that would solve all these problems!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even when his flair is [by itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651958/third-column-div-not-getting-positoined-correctly) it is too long and gets truncated.  This is very much by-design.  It's a very abnormal case for a name to be that long, and there are space limits for what have to fit everywhere.  If a name is too long, it will overflow and the overflow will be hidden.

Comment: If anything were to be done about this, I'd say it would be to automatically shorten the user name and add a trailing ellipsis in the case of overflow. But I'm not sure even that is necessary.